# Haystack with Whoosh- Search Results Not Redirecting

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, whoosh

I successfully installed whoosh and made it work with Haystack. Things are working fine but I'm facing one problem which is; after searching for a keyword and it print out the results, when I click on the result(title), It won't redirect me to the page of the keyword I clicked on, it's just static. I tried adding a get_absolute_url method. Yet it's not working. What I'm I missing?

Models

```
      class Meek(models.Model):
         user=models.ForeignKey(User)
         title=models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
         address=models.CharField(max_length=200)
         city=models.CharField(max_length=200)
         state=models.CharField(max_length=200)
         main_view=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos",blank=True, null=True)
         side_view=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos",blank=True, null=True)
         pub_date=models.DateTimeField()

         def __unicode__(self):
             return self.title


         @models.permalink
         def get_absolute_url(self):
             return ('findme', (), {
                'main_view': self.main_view,
                'side_view': self.side_view,
                'address': self.address,
                'city': self.city,
                'state': self.state})
```

Search/search.html

```
               {% block content %}

                 <h2>Search</h2>


               <form method="get" action=".">

                <table>
                  {{ form.as_table }}
                <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                 <input type="submit" value="Search">
                </td>
                </tr>
                 </table>
               {% if query %}
                 <h3>Results</h3>
              {% for result in page.object_list %}
               <p>
                <a href= "{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}" >{{ result.object.title }}</a> 
               </p>
                 {% empty %}
                    <p>No results found.</p>
                 {% endfor %}

               {% if page.has_previous or page.has_next %}
                     <div>
                       {% if page.has_previous %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page= {{ page.previous_page_number }}">{% endif %}&laquo; Previous{% if page.has_previous %}</a>
               {% endif%}

               {% if page.has_next %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page={{ page.next_page_number }}">{% endif %}Next &raquo;{% if page.has_next %}</a>{% endif %}</div>
               {% endif %}

                 {% else %}

                    {# Show some example queries to run, maybe query syntax, something else? #}

                {% endif %}
                 </form>

               {% endblock %}
```

Urlconf

```
          #url where the objects are posted.
          (r'^find/$', findme), 

         #haystack url where you can search
         (r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
```

Views:

```
           def findme(request):
               extra_data_context={}
                   #if there's nothing in the field do nothing.
               if request.method=="POST":
                  form=MeekForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
                  if form.is_valid():
                     data=form.cleaned_data
                     newmeeks=Meek(
                         user=request.user,
                         pub_date=datetime.datetime.now(),
                         title=data['title'],
                         main_view=request.FILES['main_view'],
                         side_view=request.FILES['side_view'],
                         address=data['address'],
                         city=data['city'],
                         state=data['state'])
                    newmeeks.save()
                extra_data_context.update({'MeekForm':form})
             else:
                 form = MeekForm()
                 extra_data_context.update({'MeekForm':form})
             extra_data_context.update({'Meeks':Meek.objects.filter(user=request.user)})
             return render_to_response('postme.html',extra_data_context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `get_absolute_url` your URL is called `findme` and you're giving it five parameters. In your URL configuration, the URL is there but:

- it is not called `findme` (i.e., you need to have `name="findme"`), and
- it also does not contain any parameters.

For example, the following URL has both a name and a named parameter (see [documentation on URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/) for more information):

```
(r'^articles/(?P<year>\d{4})/$', 'news.views.year_archive', name="news_year_archive"),
```

You need to create a similar URL with the parameters `main_view`, `side_view`, `address`, `city` and `state` so Django can properly reverse the URL and provide an absolute URL for the model.

Comment: still don't get it. The docs aint helping. Can you please explain further? don't you think I will write another view?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking: Django's `reverse` function is currently unable to find the URL because you're not giving the right name and parameters. If you do that, then Django can determine the URL for each object in the search results.

Comment: when user search for a keyword and it return the result, so if the user click on the result, the user should be redirected to a page where it will display every properties of the result. I hope you get my point? if you don't please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I understand that, that's what I answered above. The reverse function simply can't compute the URL right now so that's why you don't have correct links.

Comment: ok. Will I have to modify my view by doing this: def findme(request, title, main_view):
and in my url it will be; url(r'^find(?P<tiitle>\d{4})/(?P<main_view>\d{2})/$', 'views.find', name='find') please kindly put a newbie through.

Comment: You have to make sure the parameters in the URL are the same as the parameters you provide in `get_absolute_url`. In your case, there are five parameters so you have to have five parameters in the URL configuration and `get_absolute_url`. I suggest studying the documentation to see how URL configurations work as your names are currently not the same. For example, if you have `"findme"` in `get_absolute_url` then you need to have `name="findme"` in your URL configuration, not `name="find"`. Likewise, if your view is called `findme` then in the URL conf it should be `findme`, not `views.find`.