# haystack whoosh no results - rebuild_index shows Indexing [number] <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at [memory location] >

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

when I run `./manage.py rebuild_index` I get the readout for example:

`Indexing 4574 <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at at 0x1aab690> .`

Having seen other users' readouts, this should show the name of the search index/model instead and I am wondering if this could be part of the explanation as to why I have been experiencing no search results on the website and no objects appear to be indexed when performing:

```
>>> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
>>> sqs = SearchQuerySet().all()
>>> sqs.count()
```

I did not initially have a 
    def _*unicode*_self():
        return self.name
on the models I am indexing but then I added it and nothing seemed to change even after doing `rebuild_index`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176625/haystack-with-whoosh-search-results-not-redirecting

Answer (score 1):

This was GitHub [pull request #746](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/pull/746) for Django Haystack, which has now been merged.

I was seeing this same issue on my local (dev) setup.  Updating solved the "functional proxy" placeholder issue for me.

I ran the following command:

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack.git@master#egg=django-haystack
```

You may need to tweak the command to suit your own needs and/or environment.